# Is there a word similar to “verbatim” but means "too many meaningless words used"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-meaning

Is there a word similar to *verbatim* but means "Too many meaningless words used"?

I am looking for a word which describes the statement is meaningless with too many words.

Comment: ***Abstruse*** ?- difficult to penetrate; incomprehensible to one of ordinary understanding or knowledge.

Comment: Is there any other word starts with letter V - I remember a word similar to Verbatim or belongs to the family of verbatim

Comment: Got it : verbiage

Comment: Or verbose: using or expressed in more words than are needed

Comment: @Avon .. Verbose is the perfect word for my context. Thank you !!

Comment: As distinct from just the right number of meaningless words?

Comment: If you specifically want to combine the two (ordinarily unrelated) concepts of ***verbosity*** and ***meaninglessness***, how about ***waffle**?*

Comment: By "similar" do you mean it must be Latin or "latinate"?  If not, there are probably a score or more of apt adjectives.

Comment: @Josh61: No, abstruse doesn't mean "too many meaningless words used."

Comment: Verbatim doesn't mean "to use too many (meaningless) words". At least my understanding of [**verbatim**](https://www.google.it/search?q=verbatim&oq=verbatim&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=verbatim+meaning) is to quote someone's words to the exact letter. EDIT (after reading comments) Oh, you mean that **looks similar** to *verbatim*.

Comment: related: [What is the word to describe an explanatory person?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224340/what-is-the-word-to-describe-an-explanatory-person); [What is it called, when a situation is described in a complicated way instead of a simple one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203628/what-is-it-called-when-a-situation-is-described-in-a-complicated-way-instead-of)

Comment: And [What do you call the rhetoric strategy of purposefully writing a paragraph that no one can understand?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204362/what-do-you-call-the-rhetoric-strategy-of-purposefully-writing-a-paragraph-that?lq=1) and [Word to describe “when someone describes something in too much detail”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94774/word-to-describe-when-someone-describes-something-in-too-much-detail)

Comment: And [What is it called when you use many words to describe the word you want to use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232063/what-is-it-called-when-you-use-many-words-to-describe-the-word-you-want-to-use/232379#232379) and [What's a good expression for “too much information”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115739/whats-a-good-expression-for-too-much-information)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If he goes off on a *tangent* , presenting facts unrelated to his point, he is

- **circumlocutory**

or, in casual English:

- **beating {around/about} the bush**

If he simply goes on and on, using more words than necessary, he is:

- **prolix** (adj)
  or
- **verbose**  (adj)
  or
- **using **verbiage** (n)
- **windy** (or, more old-fashioned, **a windbag**)
- **long-winded** (adj.—this especially captures both the length and emptiness of a speech)

If he's extremely windy, you could use another weather-related term (for a strong or violent wind):

- **blustering** (v, adj) **blustery** (adj)

If it seems as if he just can 't talking—it seems as if he barely pauses for breath, going on as if he never pauses to think what he's saying, and often making no sense, he is "suffering" from a condition called

- **logorrhea** (it's no coincidence this sounds like *diarrhea*—it's the same thing, just coming out the other end. In fact, if he spouts all nonsense, llies and tall tales, Americans call this **bullshitting** you. So if he persists, you could refer to his (endless) **bullshit**

If he repeats himself, varying the words but not the assertion, as if repetition would prove his point better, he is:

- **belaboring the {point/issue}** (v)

or, more casually:

- **beating a dead horse** (v)

if he is overly prone to using *long words*, he is:

- **sesquipedalian** (v,n)

if he is overly prone to using *obtuse, arcane or archaic words*,  particularly if he does this to distract you from the main point by making you follow his complicated logic, he is being intentionally

- **abstruse** (adj—doesn't necessarily imply long, just complex and hard to follow)

But if he sounds as if he speaks mainly so that he can hear himself say those words, and show off his vocabulary, as if his knowledge of words constitutes knowledge of the subject (or makes up for lack of that knowlege), he is probably an incurable

- **logophile** (n)

or worse yet, if he's totally enamored of his own words...

- **logophiliac** (n)

[cf William F, Buckley]

If he goes on and on, beating you down with his rhetoric; with his opinions rather than facts, he is

- **(overly) oratorical** (adj)
  or
- **bombastic** (adj)
  or
- **bloviating**  (v,adj)... or A bloviator (n)

[cf Rush Limbaugh]

If he goes on and on, as if trying to convince you that he holds the higher moral position, he is

- **pontificating** (v)

If he goes on, trying to convince you that *your opinion is wrong*, he is

- **expostulating (at length)** (v)

If he takes too long because he spends time explaining to you things that you already understand, as if you were a simpleton, this is an extended form of

- **talking down to you**  (although this in itself does not imply long-windedness)

That's just a few off the top of my head.  I'll add dictionary references later.  Meanwhile, I recommend Merriam-Webster
http://i.word.com/

Answer (score 6):

A little bird tells me the word you might be looking for is **[verbose](https://www.google.com/search?q=verbose%20definition)**

> adjective
>  using or expressed in more words than are needed.
>   *"much academic language is obscure and verbose"*

(Google)

It seems to me to fit the requirements.

Edit: The birdy has reminded me to mention [**Tautology** (grammar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(grammar)),

> is an unnecessary repetition of meaning, using multiple words to
>   effectively say the same thing

(Wikipedia)

Neither of which necessarily mean the use meaningless words - just unnecessary ones.

To be honest, I would argue no word is truly meaningless. If it has a definition then that is its meaning.

If it is meaningless in the given context then that would, I think, be due to redundancy or superfluousness - in which case I think this answer is appropriate.

Comment: +1, even though that lil bird talks too much!

Comment: Just for clarity:  Verbose refers to *more words than necessary* but does not convey the meaning of *meaningless*!

Comment: @Josh61 Quite right thank you. I have edited to make that clear.

Comment: If this is what OP thinks is the "right" answer then I think it's a bad question, because there's no inherent implication that a *verbose* utterance should be *meaningless*. If anything, the implication is normally that there *is* meaning - but it could and should have been expressed in far fewer words. If OP *isn't* looking for the word ***verbosity*** then for the reason as given, it's a bad *answer*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I presume the OP meant superfluous instead of meaningless. As I said I don't think there's such a thing as a meaningless word.

Comment: There are words that are meaningless _to the audience being addressed_.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Each recipient might not know the meaning of the word. But that doesn't make the word meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

**verbal diarrhea** is a crude term that expresses word helplessly being expelled from one's mouth.